# D3js force layout with rectangle text groups overlapping

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Hi i am trying to use force layout of d3js... I am creating g elements with rect and text inside them. And apply force but they overlap. I think it does not solve the size of the rect. What am i doing wrong?

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
.nodes(nodes)
.links([])
.size([w, h]);

force.on("tick", function(e) {
vis.selectAll("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});

nodes.push({
w: 100,
h: 50,
val: 'dada'
});

nodes.push({
    w: 100,
    h: 50,
    val: 'zona'
});

// Restart the layout.
force.start();

var node = vis.selectAll("g")
  .data(nodes)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
.call(force.drag);

node.append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) { return d.w; })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.h; })
  .style("fill", "#eee")
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")

 node.append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.val; })
  .style("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("dy", "1em")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are attributes that you can set in your d3.layout.declaration() that will allow you to deal with the overlap, such as:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links([])
    .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(-1500)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .friction(0.5)
    .size([w, h]);
```

Important note: I borrowed data from somewhere else and ran the code. So, the values above will need to be tweaked by you. Hope this helps.